# Why is とは used over に in this Sentence?

Tags: word-choice, particle-と

`姉妹を想うが故に風太郎とは反発してる。` 
I am a bit confused by the とは where I would have expected a に/には. I don't quite know what function the と serves in this case and how the meaning would differ from に/には.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

とは is both directional(S and 風太郎 反発 each other) but には is single directional(Only S 反発 to 風太郎).
It's difference between と and に.
So, in this sentence, と/に/には can also be expected.